# How to forcefully fail drone CI

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, drone.io

I am using appleboy/SSH drone plug-in to execute my test in a remote machine and generate a test report the issue When the test in remote machine fails it shows test failed, but in the drone server it shows integration passed. Is it possible to fail the drone integration based on the results of test cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For drone to fail a step it needs to `return 1`. I assume the SSH plugin does not do that.
You could parse `stdout` for a string that indicates failure and `return 1` yourself. This could be an additional step in the CI pipeline or a single command you call after the SSH session.